# Using proxies, but it's still forwarding my own ip

Tags: python, proxy

I'm attempting to create a program, using proxies, that checks against an api. However, I can't seem to make the proxies 'work'. As they're still forwarding my personal IP address. To test this I used [this](https://api.shitchell.com/headers) to show me the IP which is forwarded. I tried changing the proxies to `https` instead of `http` but that creates a connection error, because it can't connect to the proxy.

The code which I tested the function with:

```
class main():
    with open('external/proxies.txt', 'r') as proxyFile:
        proxyList = [proxyIp.strip() for line in proxyFile.readlines() for proxyIp in line.split(',') if proxyIp]

    def proxies(self):
        self.randomProxy = random.choice(self.proxyList)
        return {"http": f"http://{self.randomProxy}"}

    def req(self):
        # proxy = return proxies()
        proxy = self.proxies()
        r = requests.get('https://api.shitchell.com/headers', proxies=proxy)
        print('prox: ', proxy)
        print('resp: ', r.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main().req()
```

The output of the code (not showing my personal ip):

```
prox:  {'http': 'http://170.254.224.7:55443'}
resp:  {
    "status": "success",
    "payload": {
        "X-Real-Ip": "my.actual.ip", 
        "X-Forwarded-For": "my.actual.ip",
        "Remote-Addr": "my.actual.ip",
        "Host": "127.0.0.1:6997",
        "Connection": "close",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.25.1",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Accept": "*/*"
    }
}
```

```
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.shitchell.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /headers (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002A84DFBEB20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    def proxies(self):
        self.randomProxy = random.choice(self.proxyList)
        return {"http": f"http://{self.randomProxy}", "https": f"https://{self.randomProxy}"}
```

Comment: That gives the connection error like previously stated. I added the error message in the post.

Comment: You can also try installing a different version of urllib3
`pip3 install urllib3==1.23`